# IHP - How to write a custom response at the end of an action?

Tags: ihp

I have POST action that ends in a custom IO operation. The server sends a 500 Internal Server Error even if the operation was successful. I need to send a custom response to deal with this. How should I do this?

My action is like this:

```hs
action MyAction { .. } = do
  .
  .
  .
  customIO
 
 responseStatusShouldBe customResponse status200
```

How should I build `customResponse`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So `customIO` has type `customIO :: IO Response`?

If that's the case you can do:

```hs
action MyAction = do
    response <- customIO
    respondAndExit response
```

[Here's an example from the IHP codebase itself where `ErrorController.buildNotFoundResponse` is of type `IO Response`:](https://github.com/digitallyinduced/ihp/blob/master/IHP/Controller/Render.hs#L102)

```hs
renderNotFound :: (?context :: ControllerContext) => IO ()
renderNotFound = do
    response <- ErrorController.buildNotFoundResponse
    respondAndExit response
```

[The `buildNotFoundResponse` is defined here.](https://github.com/digitallyinduced/ihp/blob/master/IHP/ErrorController.hs#L64)